# How come the computer keeps accessing pythonw.exe file while creating environment?

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I used `conda env export > environment.yml` to export my environment.

Then I use `conda env create -f environment.yml` to create the environment, it keeps having the pop up window saying:

> Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher
>   to make changes to this computer?
>
> Program name: pythonw.exe
>
> Publisher: unknown

I have to keep choosing yes or no, which doesn't make sense because I don't have this problem while using other people's environment file. Why is that?

I am using Anaconda, Python 3. Thanks.

The following is the environment file:

```
name: py
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - alabaster=0.7.10=py36hcd07829_0
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py36_0
  - astroid=1.6.5=py36_0
  - babel=2.6.0=py36_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py36_0
  - bcrypt=3.1.4=py36ha9ddb7d_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=2.1.3=py36_0
  - ca-certificates=2018.03.07=0
  - certifi=2018.4.16=py36_0
  - cffi=1.11.5=py36h945400d_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py36h420ce6e_1
  - cloudpickle=0.5.3=py36_0
  - colorama=0.3.9=py36h029ae33_0
  - cryptography=2.2.2=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py36h009560c_0
  - cython=0.28.3=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - decorator=4.3.0=py36_0
  - docutils=0.14=py36h6012d8f_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py36hfd66bb0_2
  - freetype=2.8=h51f8f2c_1
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py36h047fa9f_0
  - icc_rt=2017.0.4=h97af966_0
  - icu=58.2=ha66f8fd_1
  - idna=2.6=py36h148d497_1
  - imagesize=1.0.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2018.0.3=0
  - ipykernel=4.8.2=py36_0
  - ipython=6.4.0=py36_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h3c5d0ee_0
  - isort=4.3.4=py36_0
  - jedi=0.12.0=py36_1
  - jinja2=2.10=py36h292fed1_0
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h7636477_0
  - jupyter_client=5.2.3=py36_0
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py36h56e9d50_0
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py36h12c3424_0
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.3.1=py36hd1c21d2_0
  - libiconv=1.15=h1df5818_7
  - libpng=1.6.34=h79bbb47_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h9d3ae62_0
  - libxml2=2.9.8=hadb2253_1
  - libxslt=1.1.32=hf6f1972_0
  - lxml=4.2.1=py36heafd4d3_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markupsafe=1.0=py36h0e26971_1
  - matplotlib=2.2.2=py36h153e9ff_1
  - mccabe=0.6.1=py36hb41005a_1
  - mistune=0.8.3=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - mkl=2018.0.3=1
  - mkl_fft=1.0.1=py36h452e1ab_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.1=py36h9258bd6_0
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - mysql-connector-c=6.1.11=hf3e53a5_0
  - mysqlclient=1.3.12=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - nbconvert=5.3.1=py36h8dc0fde_0
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py36h3a5bc1b_0
  - notebook=5.5.0=py36_0
  - numpy=1.14.5=py36h9fa60d3_0
  - numpy-base=1.14.5=py36h5c71026_0
  - numpydoc=0.8.0=py36_0
  - openssl=1.0.2o=h8ea7d77_0
  - packaging=17.1=py36_0
  - pandas=0.23.1=py36h830ac7b_0
  - pandas-datareader=0.6.0=py36_0
  - pandoc=1.19.2.1=hb2460c7_1
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36h3ef6317_1
  - paramiko=2.4.1=py36_0
  - parso=0.2.1=py36_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0
  - pip=10.0.1=py36_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
  - psutil=5.4.6=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - pyasn1=0.4.3=py36_0
  - pycodestyle=2.4.0=py36_0
  - pycparser=2.18=py36hd053e01_1
  - pyflakes=2.0.0=py36_0
  - pygments=2.2.0=py36hb010967_0
  - pylint=1.9.2=py36_0
  - pynacl=1.2.1=py36hfa6e2cd_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py36_0
  - pyparsing=2.2.0=py36h785a196_1
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py36h1aa27d4_0
  - pysocks=1.6.8=py36_0
  - python=3.6.5=h0c2934d_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.3=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.4=py36_0
  - pywinpty=0.5.4=py36_0
  - pyzmq=17.0.0=py36hfa6e2cd_1
  - qt=5.9.5=vc14he4a7d60_0
  - qtawesome=0.4.4=py36h5aa48f6_0
  - qtconsole=4.3.1=py36h99a29a9_0
  - qtpy=1.4.2=py36_0
  - requests=2.18.4=py36h4371aae_1
  - requests-file=1.4.3=py36_0
  - requests-ftp=0.3.1=py36_0
  - rope=0.10.7=py36had63a69_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py36_0
  - setuptools=39.2.0=py36_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36_2
  - sip=4.19.8=py36h6538335_0
  - six=1.11.0=py36h4db2310_1
  - snowballstemmer=1.2.1=py36h763602f_0
  - sphinx=1.7.5=py36_0
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0=py36hbbac3d2_1
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.1.0=py36_1
  - spyder=3.2.8=py36_0
  - sqlite=3.23.1=h35aae40_0
  - terminado=0.8.1=py36_1
  - testpath=0.3.1=py36h2698cfe_0
  - tornado=5.0.2=py36_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py36h096827d_0
  - urllib3=1.22=py36h276f60a_0
  - vc=14.1=h0510ff6_3
  - vs2015_runtime=15.5.2=3
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h3d5aa90_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py36h67c50ae_1
  - wheel=0.31.1=py36_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.0.1=py36he67d7fd_1
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - wrapt=1.10.11=py36he5f5981_0
  - zeromq=4.2.5=hc6251cf_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h8395fce_2
  - pip:
    - bokeh==0.13.0
    - configparser==3.5.0
    - datetime==4.2
    - duka==0.2.0
    - ffn==0.3.4
    - fix-yahoo-finance==0.0.22
    - future==0.16.0
    - fxcmpy==1.1.26
    - googlefinance.client==1.3.0
    - inflection==0.3.1
    - more-itertools==4.3.0
    - multitasking==0.0.7
    - plotly==3.3.0
    - pyprind==2.11.2
    - pyyaml==3.13
    - quandl==3.4.2
    - retrying==1.3.3
    - scikit-learn==0.19.2
    - scipy==1.1.0
    - seaborn==0.9.0
    - socketio-client==0.7.2
    - sshtunnel==0.1.4
    - ta-lib==0.4.10
    - tabulate==0.8.2
    - websocket-client==0.48.0
    - zope.interface==4.5.0
prefix: C:\Users\AUS\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py
```

Comment: Hi, could you please specify what do you mean by words "keeps accessing"? Also "I have to keep choosing yes or no" is unclear to me too. I have a suggestion that you are struggled with tons of popup windows asking for your decision, if I'm right, what are they asking?

Comment: @mingaleg Yes you are right, I updated the question to make it clear thanks.

Comment: @merv I updated the question. Anaconda, Python 3. Thanks.